# Elasticsearch terms query problem for "text" or "keyword" type fields

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

```
"hits" : [  
  { 
    "id": 1,  
    "sampleArrayData": ["x"]
  },
  { 
    "id": 2,  
    "sampleArrayData": ["y"]
  },
  { 
    "id": 3,  
    "sampleArrayData": ["z"]
  },
  { 
    "id": 4,  
    "sampleArrayData": ["x", "y", "z"]
  },
  { 
    "id": 5,  
    "sampleArrayData": ["z", "w"]
  }
]
```

It's a sample data of index.

I want to search this index by sampleArrayData field which includes one or more values I will give dynamically.

For example if want to search this index by ["x","y"] parameters. I must get data which includes "x", or "y" or both "x", "y". (First three records from this index).
We could do this by using terms query on the old elastic search versions like below.

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "terms": {
                  "sampleArrayData": [ "x", "y"]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

But we can not use terms query for "text" or "keyword" type fields on the elasticsearch current  versions.

How can I dynamically search this index with unknown number of parameters on the C# NEST library?

Comment: you can use terms query for the current version of elasticsearch also. By using the above search query, you will get the documents having `"sampleArrayData"` as `["x"]`, `["y"]` or `[ "x", "y"]`.

Comment: I have two elasticsearch clients which has different versions old and new. I can get result from this query on the old version but I can not on new version. Actually elasticsearch offical tutorial for new versions emphasizes that we should not use term query on text, keyword type fields. I need to find different solution on the NEST library

Comment: Hi, could you share your mappings ? With nest you can use querycontainer, i will post once your mappings updated.